# Is there a way to add drop-down list of predefined variables to R-script menu in SEXTANTE QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin

I would like to create a drop-down list of variables (similar to what it is done for layers input) for my R script menu in SEXTANTE. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean pre-defined variables? E.g., variable A can take values "5" , "6" or "9"?

Comment: @FilipeDias, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that's not possible, but another user has added that as a feature request in the QGIS tracker:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8778